# When shuting down a black screen with a broken pipe message shows for half second

Tags: pipe

It is actually very fast when it shows, I had to record it to actually saw what it said and it is:

could not write bytes: Broken pipe
Checking battery state...

cpid: exiting
Checking for running unattended-upgrades

I have Ubuntu 64 bits, 12.04.3, Intel HD 4000, and I have had several problems with Ubuntu as I had to format my laptop quite a few times, I am using only Ubuntu, not Windows. Help please.

NOTE: Is a fresh install of Ubuntu 64 bits.

Answer (score 1):

I am proud to announce that I solved my problem. All I had to do was booting in GRU mode and select repair broken packages, and that was it.